How to check for CSharpCompilation reference dependency in roslyn (without trying to emit)?
Using roslyn in Unity, i created a CSharpCompilation instance. I added Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll reference to the instance using the following code
byte[] microsoftCodeAnalysisBytes = 
                Resources.Load<TextAsset>("CompilationReferences/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll").bytes;
            testAdhocWorkspaceCSharpCompilation =
                testAdhocWorkspaceCSharpCompilation.AddReferences(
                    MetadataReference.CreateFromImage(microsoftCodeAnalysisBytes)
                    );

The above code works and didn't throw any error, i can even add using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis; to code inside the CSharpCompilation. However, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll actually have a lot of dependency on other dll, and i didn't add reference to the dependency, so the CSharpCompilation won't compile if i try to emit it.
Without trying to emit the CSharpCompilation, how do i check for dll dependency for dll referenced in CSharpCompilation ?
